# Troubles with Array.every

Tags: javascript, arrays

I decided to try some manipulations with default false values in JS, but in Array.every it don't work. Could you help me with that?

[image]

Comment: please add the code (in text form) to the question and have a look here: [mcve]

Comment: What "didn't work"?  And please post your code, not pictures of your code.

Comment: The function is `forEach()`, not `.each()`

Comment: @ScottMarcus, the method is `every`.

Comment: @NinaScholz The title of the post is `each` and the first line indicates that `Array.each` was tried and didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a return statement in your test function. It should be:

```
var arr = [null];
console.log(arr.every(function(x) {
    return Boolean(x) == false;
}));
```

Comment: Yeah... That' basically why i prefer arrows for the inline functions :)

Comment: Sometimes I don't careful. 
Thanks!